# Regex matching lines with escaped new line character

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following text content:

```
npm i --save \
  gulp \
  express \
  forever
echo hi
```

I want to surround each command in its own HTML tags.

I've tried this:

```
text.replace(/(.*)[^\\\n]\n/g, (a, b) => `<pre>${b}</pre>`);
```

But that only matches last two lines. I'm looking for a way to match each line, while taking escaping into account.

The pattern should match a string that starts with a letter and ends with a new line not preceded by a `\`.

Comment: What is the rule here? Wrap a part of a string that starts with a letter on a new line and optionally includes other indented non-blank lines? See [the `/^[A-Za-z].*(?:\r?\n[^\S\r\n]{2,}\S.*)*/gm` regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o6n57N/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Lines are not always indented.

Comment: Then what is the rule? If there is no *regular*ity, *regular* expression won't help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'd say a string that starts with a letter and ending with a new line not preceded by a "\". I'm a regex noob, so if that's impossible I could just do it with JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe [`/^[A-Za-z][^]*?[^\\]$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/o6n57N/4)? Replacement in JS will be `<pre>$&</pre>`. If a command can be just 1 letter on a line, you will need [`/^[A-Za-z](?:[^]*?[^\\]$)?/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/o6n57N/5)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, that works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest

```
s = s.replace(/^[A-Za-z](?:[\s\S]*?[^\\]$)?/gm, '<pre>$&</pre>')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l1vnP2/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (due to `m` modifier the `^` matches the start of a line rather than a whole string)
- `[A-Za-z]` - an ASCII letter
- `(?:[\s\S]*?[^\\]$)?` - 1 or 0 sequences of:

  - `[\s\S]*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first occurrence of
  - `[^\\]$` - a char other than `\` at the end of a line.

Note that to replace with a capturing group value, you need not use a callback inside `String#replace`, you may use simple string replacement patterns. E.g., to reference the whole match value in the replacement, you just need to specify `$&` pattern, to replace with the first capturing group value, use `$1`, etc. See [`String#replace` MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) for more details.